# Combine the class selector with nth-child() or eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, nightwatch.js

I have a list and I want to get the first item after each heading item. I need to do this all in one line as im using Nightwatch, which hasnt got all the elasticity of using jquery in the browser. What I have is:

```
// This works
console.log('first item after first header is ');
console.log($('#ul-wrapper li.heading ~ li:first').text());

// This doesnt
console.log('first item after second header is ');
console.log($('#ul-wrapper li.heading:nth-child(2) ~ li:first').text());
```

So essentially i need to combine the class selector with nth-child() or eq(). Html is:

```
<ul id="ul-wrapper">
   <li class="heading">

        Heading 1

   </li>
   <li>
      <label>
      <a>
        Item 1
      </a>
      </label>  
   </li>
   <li>
      <label>
      <a>
        Item 2
      </a>
      </label>  
   </li>
   <li class="heading">

        Heading 2

   </li>
   <li>
      <label>
      <a>
        Item 3
      </a>
      </label>  
   </li>
   <li>
      <label>
      <a>
        Item 4
      </a>
      </label>  
   </li>
</ul>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kdr8ga2c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:nth-child()` pseudo class only looks at the index of the element relative to the parent element. Similarly, `:nth-of-type()` will only look at the index of the element based on the *type*. Neither the `:nth-child()`/`:nth-of-type()` pseudo classes will consider the element's `class` attribute.

With that being said, the `:eq()` method will select an element by it's index based on the ***filtered set*** (which is exactly what you want in this case). However, it's worth pointing out that `:eq()` has an index that is zero-based (unlike `:nth-child()`/`:nth-of-type()`). In this case, you would need to use `eq(1)` to access the second `li` element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/372ssoxn/)

```
$('#ul-wrapper li.heading:eq(1) ~ li:first');
```

---

You could also use the adjacent sibling combinator, `+`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wt2npbe8/)

```
$('#ul-wrapper li.heading:eq(1) + li');
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a list and I want to get the first item after each heading item

If I understand right you can use [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```js
$('#ul-wrapper li.heading + li').css("background", "red");
```

```css
.heading {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul-wrapper" style="">
  <li class="heading">

    Heading 1

  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <a>
       Item 1
      </a>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <a>
       Item 2
      </a>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="heading">

    Heading 2

  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <a>
       Item 3
      </a>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <a>
       Item 4
      </a>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry i should have tagged with Jquery, im using Nightwatch (http://nightwatchjs.org/), which doesnt have the .next(). You need to do everything in the selector